# Передача Unicode через Socket

Tags: delphi, сокет, unicode, delphi-10-berlin

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно передать Unicode в Delphi 10.1 Berlin с помощью Socket.
Я пытаюсь передать 日本語

Передача. Точка останова говорит, что в s находится 日本語

```
var
  s: String;
begin
  s := '日本語';
  ClientSocket1.Socket.SendText(AnsiString(s));
```

Приём

```
var
  s: String;
begin
  s := String(Socket.ReceiveText);
```

В итоге получаю ???

Comment: *Точка останова говорит, что в s находится 日本語* Угу... а Вы потом его опрессовываете AnsiString - вот и посмотрите, что получится ПОСЛЕ.

Comment: Не подскажу как тут, но в Overbyte ICS можно просто передавать указатель и длину сообщения (`TCustomWSocket.Send(Data: Pointer; Len: Integer)`). Что отдадите - то и отправится.